# Microsoft Teams not using headphones as speaker

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microsoft-teams, bose

I use a set of Bose Quite Comfort 35 II headphones for work and have been using them for a couple of years. I recently got a new HP laptop and everything was working fine for about a week, but now when I am in a Teams meeting my headphones will no longer work for a speaker. I can set it such that my headphones are the mic and my laptop speakers are in use, but if I change the speaker to the headphones there is no sound. The headphones do work fine as long as I am not in a Teams Meeting. I was also able to get them to work on a test call, but then called one of my co-workers and couldn't get it to work again. I've attempted rebooting the computer, the headphones, and even re-paired the headphones to the computer with no change. I did have a strange message pop up asking if this was a personal conference call, but it went away before I could even tell which application was asking it (I think it was something from HP, but I am not 100% sure).

The laptop is an HP ZBook Fury, 64GB ram, Intel Xeon W-11955M processor, running Windows 10 version 19044.

Comment: It seems you have to set then for HFP ("hands free" profile) before using the software. The popup would probably do that had you answered yes.

Comment: What happens if you follow [this advice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-modern-usb-headset-in-microsoft-teams-2e906422-2766-48ad-954c-1ebdd94c5f18) ?

Comment: @harrymc I have a Bluetooth headset, not a usb headset.

Comment: It's rather [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-modern-wireless-headset-in-microsoft-teams-5e2ffae3-d2ad-409a-bc81-56d1d5a8999e).

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out what needed to change thanks to this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-bose-bluetooth-headset-no-audio-in-meetings/1e2e3178-977c-4d78-bd50-c16ab4843591

The primary steps are as follows:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Go to Devices and Printers (need to be in icon view to find it)
3. Right click your headphones
4. Click on properties
5. Uncheck Handsfree Telephony

I wish I knew what caused this to be set this way in the first place, but at least I know how to fix it now.

Comment: This appeared to work, but now I realize that though my headphones are now working, Teams will no longer allow me to select the mic on my headset.